# Android.Clean Arch. Send data from domain to data layer

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

Okay, we have 3 layers for clean architecture (presentation, domain, data). Data layer has reference to Domain layer, but Domain layer haven't any references to other layers.

```
**Domain layer:**

class SendDataInteractor(
  val repository: Repository,
  val data: Data
): ObservableUseCase<Response>() {
  override fun buildObservableUseCase(): Observable<Response> {
      repository.sendData(?)
  }
}

**Data layer:**

fun sendData(data: DataEntity): Observable<Response> {
    
}
```

How can i send data from domain layer to data layer, if Domain layer don't know about "DataEntity" type? I thought one desicion: use "Any" type instead of DataEntity.

How is this problem solved in such applications?

Comment: The approach here would be to retrieve the domain layer model in the data layer and then map it to the data layer object